# MySQL Join multiple rows based on an interval

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following mysql table:

```
Start Time  End Time    Duration
17:00:02    17:00:31    00:00:29    
17:02:30    17:02:41    00:00:11    
17:11:25    17:15:25    00:04:00    
17:15:37    17:17:51    00:02:14    
17:18:08    17:20:17    00:02:09    
17:20:35    17:20:37    00:00:02    
17:20:39    17:21:25    00:00:46    
17:21:33    17:22:02    00:00:29
```

I need to merge the rows whenever the duration is less than 2 minutes: which should look like this:

```
Start Time  End Time    Duration
17:00:02    17:15:25    00:04:40    
17:15:37    17:17:51    00:02:14    
17:18:08    17:20:17    00:02:09    
17:20:35    17:22:02    00:01:17
```

How could this be done? 
You can assume the start time/end time/duration are already in unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggle, here it is:

```
select min(start_time) start_time, max(end_time) end_time, 
  TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(sum(duration)),'%i:%s') duration
from (
  select start_time, end_time, duration, 
    if (@dur>=120, @grp:=@grp+1, @grp) g,
    if (@dur>=120, @dur:=duration, @dur:=@dur+duration) dur
  from mytable a
  join (select @dur:=0, @grp:=0) b) a
group by a.g;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a748d8/14)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by assigning a group to each of the rows and then aggregating by the group.  The group, in this case, is the number of times that records with a duration of more than 2 minutes appear earlier in the data:

```
select min(StartTime) as StartTime, max(EndTime) as EndTime, sum(Duration) as Duration
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from table t2
              where t2.StartTime < t.StartTime and
                    t2.Duration >= '00:02:00'
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Comment: Very clever solution. If I were doing it in SQL, I'd probably have done it with an `@` variable that I increment every time I hit a long duration, and use that as the grouping column.

Comment: @Barmar . . . It is a reasonable solution until the table starts to have a few thousand rows.  But the OP doesn't mention performance, and it is reasonable for small tables.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I did my solution in PHP. It's linear in the number of rows, not quadratic.

Comment: @Barmar, that's exactly what I did

Comment: @Fabricator Cool, now we have all 3 approaches! The OP can decide which one he likes.

Answer (score 0):

This may be most efficient to do in PHP than MySQL:

```
$results = array();
$curstart = null;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($curstart == null) {
        $curstart = $row['start_time'];
        $curdur = 0;
    }
    $curdur += $row['duration'];
    $curend = $row['end_time']
    if ($row['duration'] >= 120) {
        $results[] = array('start_time' => $curstart, 
                           'end_time' => $end_time,
                           'duration' => $curdur);
        $curstart = null;
        $curdur = 0;
    }
}
if ($curstart != null) { // Get last block if it didn't end with duration > 2 min
    $results[] = array('start_time' => $curstart, 
                       'end_time' => $end_time,
                       'duration' => $curdur);
}
```